# HTML5 localStorage overwrite data

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I am working with LocalStorage for the first times for a web app I am working on. However I have hit upon a problem that I hope someone will be able to help me with,

Using localStorage I am saving a JSON object too it. This JSON object gives somewhere to store data and pull data from to drive my web app, without the need for a database connection of LAMP server. So is the ideal solution for.

On the web app start the user makes some choices that drive what JSON files the app uses to startup with the code for this is here,

```
makeSelection: function(element) {

        var that = this;

        element.parents('.column-wrapper').find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        element.addClass("selected");

        if(element.data("collection") != undefined) {
            $.getJSON('json/' + element.data("collection") + '.json', function(data){
                localStorage.setItem('collection', JSON.stringify(data));
            });
        }

        if(element.data("room") != undefined) {
            localStorage.getItem('room');
        }
    }
```

Now the above code works fine, if I `console.log(localStorage.getItem('collection')` then I get

```
{collection: "{"name":"Default JSON 1"}"}
```

which I would expect, however at any point the user can change where their data comes from meaning running the `makeSelection` function again. The user then for example selects default JSON 2, I check the network tab, and see that the request has been made for that JSON file, and the JSON has been returned.

I run `console.log(localStorage.getItem('collection')` again expecting to get

```
{collection: "{"name":"Default JSON 2"}"}
```

as I requested that JSON file, and I can that JSON as the response in my network tab, however what I get in my console is still,

{collection: "{"name":"Default JSON 1"}"}

Should running `makeSelection()` not change the collection item in localStorage to match that of the `getJSON` response?

Am I missing a step, or using localStorage incorrectly?

Comment: Are you switching domains or even from http to https?

Comment: No domain switching the only thing that changes is the file that gets Called in getJSON request

Comment: does there have to be a page between localStorage being written?

Comment: no you can access localStorage as many times as you like on any page, the only reason i asked is because if the domain changes or the protocol changes, you have a different localStorage instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only explanation is that your callback is not being triggered.

```
localStorage.setItem('collection', 'data 1'); (function () { return  localStorage.getItem('collection');})();

> "data 1"

localStorage.setItem('collection', 'data 2'); (function () { return  localStorage.getItem('collection');})();

> "data 2"
```

Have you tried doing some debugging? Such as

```
if(element.data("collection") != undefined) {
        $.getJSON('json/' + element.data("collection") + '.json', function(data){
            console.log('CAME INTO CALLBACK');
            localStorage.setItem('collection', JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('FINISHING CALLBACK');
        });
```

My guess is that you'll see neither of those prints in the console when you run your code.